# Travis CI Ruby exited with 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

I built a new rails app and when I have configured the .travis.yml file it exits with one all the time.
Here is my travis configuration:

```
language: ruby
node_js:
  - 12
cache:
  bundler: true
  yarn: true
services:
  - redis-server
sudo: required
before_install:
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
addons:
  postgresql: '9.6'
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database product_hunt_clone_test;' -U postgres
script:
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec rake db:schema:load
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - SECRET_KEY_BASE=a RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  - bundle exec rake test
  - bundle exec rake test:system
```

and here are the errors travis is giving me:
[screenshot from travis console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nD9G.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have apparently create [the initial application](https://github.com/marachimeno/camillion-api) using the `--skip-sprockets` parameter. As such, you have disable the use of the assets pipeline in your application and with that have disable the need (and possibility) to run `rake assets:precompile`.

If you do need assets pipeline (and thus the `rails-sprockets` gem), you can re-enable it by adding

```
gem "sprockets-rails"
```

to your `Gemfile` and uncommenting the line

```
# require "sprockets/railtie"
```

in your `config/application.rb` file. You would also need to create the asset files as necessary. Please refer to the [documentation for the assets pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline-questionmark) for details.

If you actually want to skip the assets pipeline, you can just remove the call to the `assets:precompile` task from your `.travis.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you correctly installing your gems (with `bundle install`) before executing your rake commands? Seems like you would need sprockets before compiling the assets.

Comment: I have run bundle install before pushing the changes but it still gives me the same error. How would I use sprockets?

Comment: Did you run bundle install locally or on the TravisCI server?
Try adding `- bundle install` right under `script`

Comment: I ran bundle install locally. It's still giving me the same error after adding ```- bundle install```